# How to enable indirect GLX contexts (+iglx) in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with nvidia gfx-cards

Tags: server, ssh, xorg, opengl, remote

I am running a linux-host for Qt-software-development at a central place.

With my windows box I use Xming as a local X-server and putty to connect to that linux-host. With this configuration I can use all X (xclock, xterm) and GLX (qtcreator, gxlinfo, glxgears...) programs at the linux-host.

My main workstation is a ubuntu 14.04 LTS with a nvidia gfx card. When I connect to the linux-host with my ubuntu-system using "ssh -p port# -YC my.dev.host.com" I also **can use** all X programs (xclock, xterm) programs but I **can not use** GLX programs (qtcreator, gxlinfo, glxgears...).

As far I [learned](http://http.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/340.76/README/xconfigoptions.html) this is because the X-server dont support indirect GLX contexts by default for version younger 1.16.

So my questions ist: How can I enable indirect GLX contexts (X-server and nvidida driver) in my ubuntu 14.04 LTS installation to get things working as expected from a X-server.

Thank you for any help!

cmks

Here is the output of glxgears, maybe that helps:

```
root@my.dev.host.com:~# LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxgears 
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /root/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /root/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  35
  Current serial number in output stream:  37
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar issue when running some GL applications via 'ssh -X' and solved it by adding "+iglx" to xserver-command in /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf.

```
[SeatDefaults]
# Dump core
xserver-command=X -core +iglx
```

After which you either reboot or Ctrl-Alt-F1, login, and 'sudo service lightdm restart'.

I hope this helps!

Comment: glxdemo, glxheads and glxinfo are working now. glxgears starts but shows only the first frame. I guess it is related to "Running synchronized to the vertical refresh."  There are still the messages `libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found` and `libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast`

Comment: The libGL errors are caused by the try to use DRI. Setting `LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1` prohibits using of DRI in then there are no error messages. But glxgears still only shows one frame

Comment: Could your glxgears crash be: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99555 ? Looks like IGLX is broken in Xorg for about a year :(

Comment: Can you clarify if you edited the client (the computer which run ssh -X) or the server (the computer with the ssh server)?

Answer (score 7):

An alternative (and display-manager-independent) way to add the options is to add the following section to /etc/X11/xorg.conf:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "IndirectGLX" "on"
EndSection
```

Comment: My xorg.conf keeps getting overwritten everytime I restart `lightdm`.

Comment: @ArcaneDominion Put commands in a  file in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d (at least on xubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue running a custom OpenGL program over `ssh -X`.  The above solution worked with a slight modification

```
Section "ServerFlags"  
    Option "AllowIndirectGLX" "on"  
    Option "IndirectGLX" "on"  
EndSection
```

This worked with ubuntu 16.04 server running kubuntu-desktop with NVIDIA GTX 1070 GPU and NVIDIA binary driver installed through apt.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about where to add this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: Seems like the right setting is [`Option "IndirectGLX" "on"`](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/tree/hw/xfree86/common/xf86Config.c#n706).  According [to this](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/tree/glx/glxcmds.c#n283), `enableIndirectGLX` must evaluate to `TRUE` so the `BadValue` error is not returned.  The default is: `FALSE` = `-iglx` (on command line).  So on of either set: `+iglx` command line option, OR `IndirectGLX "on"` or [equivalent "truthy" value](https://github.com/nwnk/xserver/blob/d2e57f71ad16f1e677dd542a8bc0db87dfa9791d/hw/xfree86/doc/ddxDesign.xml#L3382-L3398)

Comment: Nvidia docs for the binary drivers say there is another option [`AllowIndirectGLXProtocol`](https://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/340.98/README/xconfigoptions.html) for the same thing. However, their docs are somewhat confusing, because they mention the `BadValue` error will be returned with their setting name as `AllowIndirectGLXProtocol = "true"`. This is completely opposite of what they say later "`The NVIDIA GLX implementation will prohibit creation of indirect GLX contexts if AllowIndirectGLXProtocol option is set to False.`"
So it's confusing, and maybe docs are wrong?